# checking user visit specific url in website

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I want to do some action when user visit specific URL in my website.

```
    add_action('template_redirect', 'woocommerce_custom_redirections');
    function woocommerce_custom_redirections() {
    $MyLoginURL = "https://example.com/?login=true&page=4";
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() )
        wp_redirect($MyLoginURL);
    /*i want to change "is_account_page()" with "$MyLoginURL" in the line below*/
    if( is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() )
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
}
```

How can I use conditional statement with specific URL(in this case:"$MyLoginURL")?

*Note: comment on the code is showing the problem.
Any help will be appreciated.*

Comment: $link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 
                "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  // get current url

Comment: @Bhavik gajjar, thankyou very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current page url:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')   
     $url = "https://";   
else  
     $url = "http://";   
// Append the host(domain name, ip) to the URL.   
$url.= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];   

// Append the requested resource location to the URL   
$url.= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    

echo $url;
```

do  some conditions with `$url` variable.